# Print Layout not showing repeating table headers ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, tableheader

I'm trying to show the tables' headers on every new page and it is working in the usual preview mode in reporting services but it isn't working when showing the report in print layout mode. It shows the headers on some of the pages but only when my parent group is at the top of the page which it rarely is cause of the other "child-tables" data that shows after.

I've been following some other SO-posts where they suggest going in to advanced mode by the column group, choose the static field belonging to the table headers, putting "KeepWithGroup"-property to AFTER and the "RepearOnNewPage"-property to TRUE and ofcourse in the tablix properties check the "Repeat header columns on each page"-box. 
While doing everything that people are suggesting in other SO-posts I just can't get it to work.

The image below shows what the table looks like, where the yellow marked area is the header and the red is the "child-table" I put in after merging that row. Between the marked rows is the parent table which the child table is ordered by.
[The layout of the table in the report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Fyz.png)

Please help me, this is such an annoying problem!

EDIT ---

Okay, so I get that the headers follow the group and that the "KeepWithGroup" = After shows the headers only when the group starts at the top of the page.
Is there any workaround to make the header showing on every page without making it a page header?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow all the other advice readily available on this topic:

```
RepeatOnNewPage property to **True**.
KeepWithGroup property to **After**.
```

But then, make sure your lowest level Group has the KeepTogether property set to **True**.

Otherwise, you'll just be hoping your data breaks on the page for the header to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

After **much pain** with this exact issue, even setting RepeatOnNewPage to true and KeepWithGroup property to After...ultimately the fix was adjusting the top and bottom margins of the report.

The weird part is that the headers correctly repeat in the report preview, but not after clicking the print layout button.

changing the **top and bottom margin from 0.25 to 1** fixes the repeating header issue, but then adds some white space. I'm still trying to figure out the causal relationship between margin and why it breaks the header repeating...but it does fix the problem for some reason.